# Type alias with compile-time checking?

Tags: f#, typechecking, type-alias

**Type Aliases do not provide compile-time type checking**

Type aliases are very handy for shortening long type names. Type alias' are just syntatic sugar and are compiled into the aliased type at run-time, meaning two different aliases representing the same type can be used interchangeably without error:

```
type foo = int
type bar = int

let x : foo = 5
let y : bar = x
```

> `type foo = int`
>   `type bar = int`
>   `val x : foo = 5`
>   `val y : bar = 5`

I understand why you wouldn't want to treat them as regular types with compile-time type enforcement. Still, in some scenarios, it would be very handy.

**Sometimes, I need to differentiate between ints which represent different things**

For example, I am importing some functions from a COM library that has several different kinds of values, but they are all represented as `int`s in my code:

```
[<DllImport(@"C:\API\COMAPI.dll", EntryPoint="Foobar")>]
extern int Foobar ( int hPool, int hServer )
```

In C, `hPool` is of type `APIP` and `hServer` and the function return type are both `APIV`:

```c
typedef unsigned long  API_INDEX;      // index 
typedef API_INDEX    * APIV;           // value handle
typedef void         * APIP;           // pool  handle
```

I would like to represent these different types, representing different things, with different types that provide some compile-time type enforcement. That way, I can't accidentally pass an APIP to a function expecting an APIV.

**Measures get me half-way there, but require a LOT of extra fluff**

So far, the only solution I've found is to use measurements:

```
type [<Measure>] APIP
type [<Measure>] APIV
```

Unfortunately, it seems that measures cannot be added directly to externs:

```
[<DllImport(@"C:\API\COMAPI.dll", EntryPoint="Foobar")>]
extern int<APIV> _Foobar ( int<APIP> hPool, int<APIV> hServer )
```

> `error FS0010: Unexpected type application  in extern declaration. Expected identifier or other token.`

So I am having to write a wrapper function, resulting in a LOT of extra code:

```
[<DllImport(@"C:\API\COMAPI.dll", EntryPoint="Foobar")>]
extern int private _Foobar ( int hPool, int hServer )
let Foobar ( hPool : int<APIP> ) ( hServer : int<APIV> ) : APIV =
    _Foobar( int hPool, int hServer ) |> LanguagePrimitives.Int32WithMeasure
```

Multiplied by dozens and dozens of imported functions, this is getting really bloated and tiresome.

**Is there a more intuitive way to handle this, or am I stuck deciding between compile-time type checking and reasonably readable code?**

Comment: What happens if you apply the measures directly to the `extern` declarations?

Comment: Given that units of measure are erased at compile-time, I think that adding them on the `extern` declaration should actually work (as Daniel suggests).

Comment: Not related to your direct question, but given those C definitions, the correct interop signature is `extern unativeint Foobar(nativeint hPool, unativeint hServer)` (unless you're intentionally restricting yourself to 32-bit processes and ignoring signedness).

Comment: @ildjarn - Hmm... according to [*Real World Functional Programming: With Examples in F# and C#*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh304361(v=vs.100).aspx): "When declaring the prototype of a native routine, F# uses the native C notation. ... Note that the pointer definition uses double* with the C meaning. This means that double is equivalent to System.Double, which is the same as float in F#. It is possible to use any of these names."

Comment: I thought you were intentionally avoiding pointers since you didn't use any. :-] If not, it should be `extern uint32* Foobar(void* hPool, uint32* hServer)`, which makes your question moot for this specific case.

Comment: @ildjarn - Won't that produce [unverifiable code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340434.aspx), though? I'm not sure that I'll be able to run this code with sufficient trust in the "production" environment.

Comment: In which case you're back to using `nativeint`. Either way, `int` is wrong for all three since they're all pointers.

Comment: @ildjarn - Good grief... I hate interop. It's hard to find any decent documentation on what's proper to use in which situations and why. So far, all of my API calls have worked just fine with `int`. What trouble am I going to run into by using int?

Comment: Possible silent memory corruption in a 32-bit process, and definite stack corruption in a 64-bit process.